# GCM not receiving messages on android 4.0.4 device

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-messaging, android-manifest

I'm trying to get GCM working on a device with android 4.0.4. 
First of all, sending from the device to the server to another device is no problem, it's the receiving part that won't work. Second, I'm also working with a device with android 5 and on that phone it all works fine. I think it might have something to do with the device, but I'm not sure (MEDION p4013). It's android 4.0.4 so you don't need a google account to make it work, but to be sure I also activated an account on the phone but still no result.

here is my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"/>

<permission android:name="com.example.tom.stapp3.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.tom.stapp3.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:name=".application.StApp">

    <receiver android:name=".gcm.GCMBroadCastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"/>
            <category android:name="com.example.tom.stapp3"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service android:name=".gcm.GCMMessageHandler"/>
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>

    <service
        android:name=".service.ShimmerService"
        android:enabled="true">
    </service>

    <activity
        android:name=".activity.FragmentViewer"
        android:label="Stapp 3" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.ProfileView"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_profile_view">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.LeaderboardView"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_leaderboard_view"
        android:launchMode="singleTop">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".activity.StrangerView"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_stranger_view">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.tom.stapp3.activity.LeaderboardView" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.ConnectionView"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_connection_view" >
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".activity.QuestList"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_quest_view" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.SoloQuestDescription"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_quest_description" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.GraphView"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_graph">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.GCMTestActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_internet__connection" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

the broadcast receiver:

```
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(), GCMMessageHandler.class.getName());
            Log.d("received", "message");
            startWakefulService(context, intent.setComponent(comp));
            setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
        }
```

and the handler:

```
private Handler handler;

public GCMMessageHandler() {
    super("GCMMessageHandler");
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    handler = new Handler();
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
    String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);
    final int challengeId = Integer.parseInt(extras.getString("challenge_id"));
    final String message = extras.getString("message");
    handler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if(challengeId == -1) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                //TODO implementatie
            }
        }
    });
    GCMBroadCastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
}
```

Comment: Does this device has Google Play Store or Google Play Services installed?

Comment: yes the device has it installed. I now made it work outside the project. So if the upper code is in another project it works fine. I can receive messages. But when I implement it in my original project it doesn't work even if the code is the same... I really don't know what is going wrong !!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok I found it,

the problem was in the build.gradle of the app. The applicationId did not match the package name of the application. Apparently with older versions of android you get a problem, but with newer versions it changes it somewhere automatically.